# Front-end web development - work demand in Saskatchewan

Tags: canada, resident-permit, canadian-citizens

Does any body have an idea about the demand of front end web development work of IT sector in Saskatchewan?

I am moving to this province with PR status with these technical skills.

Comment: Html/css/javascrip-angularjs. Am good in these technologies.

Comment: [Zero demand on the government job portal](https://emploisfp-psjobs.cfp-psc.gc.ca/psrs-srfp/applicant/page2440?locationsFilter=saskatchewan&departments=&title=web%20development&tab=1&search=Search%20jobs&addedLocation=P7&officialLanguage=&log=false) Although you should check other job portals.

Comment: @DipenShah This is the better place to find [jobs](http://jobs.cips.ca/jobseeker/search/results/state/Saskatchewan)

Comment: See my answer for more.

Comment: @DipenShah After I receive PR, If I do not get job in SK, then, I can move to other province. I heard that halifax has less competition for jobs.

Comment: Don't go on what you hear. You should narrow it down on the basis of facts. And let me tell you after coming here, weather is the biggest factor you will take account into.

Comment: @DipenShah I got PR for NZ as well, but I am preferring CANADA. NZ has better climate than CANADA. My mind says to move to NZ. My heart says to move to CANADA.NZ is very good in FrontEndDev market.BTW, my office colleague is working halifax.

Comment: If that suits you the best then go for it.

Comment: Do you have an update for this? You can post your own answer if you found something better or mark the answer as accepted so that it helps future visitors.

Comment: @overexchange Just curious where did you move to? And how are you enjoying the new country?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the job search pages and websites that I found for you which I use in Ontario for job search.

> **DISCLAIMER:** While these job portals seem to provide many jobs, not all jobs you see are real on these portals. Watch out for money
>   launderers, scams, etc.

1. [Indeed Canada](http://www.indeed.ca): This is where you will find the most (that includes fake postings, scams, etc) jobs. [Jobs for SK](http://ca.indeed.com/IT-jobs-in-Saskatchewan)
2. [SaskJobs](https://www.saskjobs.ca/jsp/joborder/listing.jsp?filter_by=2&noc_skill_type=2) This shows roughly 350 jobs at the moment.
3. [Government job site](http://www.jobbank.gc.ca/job_search_results.do?searchstring=web+development&action=Search) Shows around 2K jobs right now but I doubt most of them are not real.
4. [Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/saskatoon-web-developer-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,9_IC2291672_KO10,23.htm) shows just 1 search result.
5. [Workopolis](http://www.workopolis.com/jobsearch/it-jobs/saskatchewan-canada) again shows just 1 job as of now.
6. [CIPS](http://jobs.cips.ca/jobseeker/search/results/state/Saskatchewan) shows promising results. However again watch out for fake postings.
7. [Simply Hired](http://www.simplyhired.ca/search?q=Software&l=Saskatchewan) shows around 700 jobs as of now.
8. [Wow Jobs](http://www.wowjobs.ca/BrowseJobsCity.aspx?p=SK) shows some jobs however I am not aware of the quality of the jobs they have.
9. [Monster](http://jobsearch.monster.ca/Saskatchewan_1?sf=21&q=web-development) shows less than 10 results which includes jobs in Regina.
10. [Kijiji](http://www.kijiji.ca/b-programmer-computer-jobs/saskatchewan/c54l9009) I would not recommend this as a lot of people have not recommended me to use Kijiji; However to contradict myself, I found the job that I currently work at Kijiji.

I let you make the best decision with these numbers. You can compare these numbers with other provinces if you want.